# create and use one object in another in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a variable/object called Student.
it's attributes are: name,surname,address.I want it to have one more attribute-"classroom", All I want is to create a new object classroom,which attributes will be "class_number" and "class_type"...
So I want:

```
 var student : [{
    name: "Jacob"
    surname:"Black"
    adress:"Baltimore Street N2",
    classroom: // I dont know how to write this
    }];
```

Comment: var student : [{
    name: "Jacob"
    surname:"Black"
    adress:"Baltimore Street N2",
    classroom: {"class_number":"0001", "class_type":"primary"}
    }];

Comment: Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var student : [{
    name: "Jacob"
    surname:"Black"
    adress:"Baltimore Street N2",
    classroom: {
        "class_number":"101",
        "class_type":"programming"
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do as follows:

```
var classroom = {
      class_number : xxx;
      class_type : 'xxx';
    }

student.classroom = classroom;
```